# C# DataGridView DefaultCellStyle.Format not working for dd/MM/yyyy with auto-generated columns

Tags: c#, date, datagridview, format

I have a DataGridView that auto-generates the columns from the datasource (a SQL query).

One of those fields is a DATE field (specifically converted to a DATE in the SQL query).

However, the DataGridView still shows it with a TIME portion, of 00:00:00, despite setting the DefaultCellStyle.Format to "dd/MM/yyyy", and the ValueType to typeof(System.DateTime);

Code:

```
dgvCharges.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
dgvCharges.DataSource = devChargesSchema.Tables["Charges"].DefaultView;
dgvCharges.AutoGenerateColumns = false;

dgvCharges.Columns["dNextChargeDate"].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
dgvCharges.Columns["dNextChargeDate"].HeaderText = "Next Charge Date";
dgvCharges.Columns["dNextChargeDate"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "dd/MM/yyyy";
dgvCharges.Columns["dNextChargeDate"].ValueType = typeof(System.DateTime);
```

I've searched for this issue, and all the replies say to do what I already have.

I've tried:-

With and without the ValueType

Setting the format to "dd-MM-yyyy", "yyyy/MM/dd" and "yyyy-MM-dd"

With the ValueType before and after the DefaultCellStyle

Removing dgvCharges.AutoGenerateColumns = false;

Removing .DefaultView; from the DataSource set line

All combinations of the above

No matter what I try, the column is always shown as dd-MM-yyyy 00:00:00

The Time is always there, the separator is always a hyphen not a slash, and the order is always dd MM yyyy even if I tell it to be yyyy MM dd

Comment: Are you sure your column isn't a string?

Answer (score 0):

Solved: it was getting converted into a string in a section between the SQL query and the DataGridView.

After SeM's comment I double-checked through all the code (it's ancient code I inherited), and a schema that was being used in the middle had the field defined as a string instead of a DateTime.

Changed the definition, and now it all works properly.

Thanks SeM! :)